# Laravel 5.3 store and read file directories

Tags: php, file, laravel-5, storage

Currently trying to play about with files but struggling to figure out where to put them and how to read them back in a list.

Ive tried putting few test files into

```
$files = array();
$dir = opendir(asset('files'); // open the cwd..also do an err check.
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")) {
            $files[] = $file; // put in array.
    }   
}
```

but it just returns blank despite having 3 test files in it.

Looked into larval recipes and suggestions say File:allFile() which isn't a supported method but its got me wondering apart from how to read  files from a directory, where should  i be really storing files I'm going to have on a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel 5.3 uses [`Storage` instead of `Files`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem). You can access all of the files in a directory using either of these two methods:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$files = Storage::files($directory);

$files = Storage::allFiles($directory); // Includes subdirectories
```

Comment: Passing it a public director path it seems to return empty array?

Comment: Make sure you're passing in the correct path. For the Storage class, I believe that it should be relative to your project directory. So if your folder is `storage/files`, that's what you should pass in. You may need to tweak it. You can also try logging `Storage::dirname($directory);` to find out exactly where it's looking.

Comment: Files I've put to test are in storage/files just simple test.txt however when i set $directory = storage/files its still returning email

Comment: Try the logging and make sure it's looking where you think it is. Sometimes file paths get a little wonky. Also check the permissions of the files.

Comment: Using it on my local machine so set the permission to 777, set the directory to 1. $directory = "storage/files/"

Comment: $files = Storage::allFiles($directory); // Includes subdirectories

            foreach ($files as $file)
            {
                print_r($file);
                echo "<hr>";
            }

Comment: Nothing still blank, I'm not familiar with larval all that too well so apologies

Comment: Try this: `\Log::info(Storage::dirname($directory));` or `print_r(Storage::dirname($directory))`, and see what it shows.