# Laravel 5.4 RuntimeException] Directory name must not be empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm just learning Laravel 5 and I am loving it.

I have an issue though, my `php artisan` command just stopped working all of a sudden. It shows this error

```
[RuntimeException]
Directory name must not be empty.
```

I am running on a windows10 pc . Thanks

Comment: Did use use **composer install** command?

Comment: @OdinThunder, how do you mean? I don't think i did anything like that

Comment: try to execute command `composer update`

Comment: It's a question answered a LOT of times: artisan is part of your project. You screwed something in your project, absolutely NOT related with artisan, and now your project doesn't work, artisan included. Check your most recent changes in your code to see where you introduced the error. EXTRA HINT: it's something related with directories.

Comment: @bluemoon, thanks for the help but it didn't work because in the end of updating, it ran `php artisan optimize` and same error came up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 store and read file directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091445/laravel-5-3-store-and-read-file-directories)

Comment: @kqa it's not a duplicate and they're not even related

Answer (score 2):

Today I got the same issue while working on local environment, I really don't know how but my **config** folder was deleted automatically. Fortunately, I had backup with me and I simply re-add the **config** folder into my project and my site is back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your `composer` like:

```
composer update
```

OR

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

after you can clear the cache

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```