# My php artisan command has just stopped working. I get a "[RuntimeException] Directory name must not be empty" error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I was happily following along one of the Laracasts episodes and suddenly my php artisan command stopped working. I just get "[RuntimeException] Directory name must not be empty"

I have googled this problem and nothing seems to help. The most common answer is to update my composer and then run php artisan config:cache and then clear but this misses the whole point as I am UNABLE to run php artisan at all, even after I update my composer.

What do I do? I would like to understand why its saying my Directory Name is empty? What Directory is this talking about?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Could you please add more details? Did you make any changes in any part of your code? Did you try get verbose output from artisan to see more details about the error?

Comment: Nothing to do with artisan here. You have an error in your code somewhere. Backtrack. If you're using git and comitting changes, rollback until it works again, then cherry pick forward. If not, perform the same methodology, but by hand.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43780651/4939915) answer, hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem have to be from your path check out your current working directory by:

```
echo __DIR__;
```

And make sure from your template path.

Also checkout what **realpath()** function returns if you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying and trying to assist.

Solution: I figured out that some files were suddenly missing. I literally compared this laravel project with another one that did work and kept replacing files / folders until it started working.

I have NO idea how those files disappeared but at least now its fixed.

Thanks all.